# Magento 2 Product Price and MSRP

Tags: magento2.3

I understand that `Magento 2` if you enable `MAP` then the product price doesn't display on the `frontend`.
I need both `msrp` and price to be displayed on the `frontend`, for product list page, product page so I'm looking to see if anyone has a solution for this.
I can add a `msrp` and regular price in the admin.
Can anyone advise me please?
Many Thanks in Advance

### Andy.

Would there be any implications if I created a 'custom_msrp' attribute for the product msrp?
I'm thinking I could do this and then use an if statement in the frontend to display the new attribute value if it was other than null.

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have this same question. I need to show MSRP AND my price for each product, then to use "special price" for sales on occasion.

Currently I can only make "price" show the MSRP, and have to use "special price" for my price, with no room for sales.

It seems a huge oversight to not have MSRP as an easy option.